# How to make columns items overlap a pretty bit on their borders

Tags: flutter, dart

i have the following code

```
Column(
  children: [
    Container(
      width: 200,
      height: 300,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.red,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 150,
      height: 200,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.blue,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
    ),
    Container(
      width: 100,
      height: 150,
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
          color: Colors.green,
          borderRadius:BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(15.0)),
      ),
    ),
  ],
)
```

the output in `UI` is normal. but i am trying to make the design like following

[image]

i tried to use `Stack` but the problem that stack does not fit my case because the items size are not fixed so will have problems. the `height` and `width` in my previous example are only as example but in the fact the valuse depending on items content that Column handle this auto

Comment: wrap your `Containers` with `Align` with `heightFactor` < 1

Comment: Aweee , thanks Man , it work like a charm ,I was so close to despair , really thanks ... Wonder why don't you post it as  answer !

Comment: sorry I was too hasty to express my opinion , after test i find out that if item was big in height so the items act weird , they don't be the same same given height factor

Answer (score 2):

You can use Stack with Positioned widget to achieve this ui,
Below you can check that code.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    class ExamplePage extends StatefulWidget {
      const ExamplePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
    
      @override
      State<ExamplePage> createState() => _ExamplePageState();
    }
    
    class _ExamplePageState extends State<ExamplePage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        var mq = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
        return Scaffold(
          body: SafeArea(
            child: Stack(
              clipBehavior: Clip.none,
              children: [
                customContainer(
                  width: mq.width * 0.80,
                  height: mq.height * 0.25,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -130,
                  child: customContainer(
                    width: mq.width * 0.72,
                    height: mq.height * 0.21,
                    color: Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                Positioned(
                  bottom: -210,
                  child: customContainer(
                    width: mq.width * 0.65,
                    height: mq.height * 0.17,
                    color: Colors.green,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    
      Widget customContainer({
        required double height,
        required double width,
        required Color color,
      }) {
        return Container(
          width: width,
          height: height,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: color,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

output:

[image]

Comment: thanks . your code is working in case if the stack was out of any scroll widget , if not so all the negative Positioned values gonna be invisible out the screen zone .. if you could find a way to solve this problem i am gonna accept your answer with thanks